# Remove all after certain character

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have got a C# project and some data like:

```
Thinness (n.)
Slenderness (n.)
A fat lot
Hefty (a.)
Tucking of loincloth
```

I want these data just like that below

```
Thinness 
Slenderness 
A fat lot
Hefty 
Tucking of loincloth
```

I tried

```
UPDATE    dic
SET  english = LEFT(english, CHARINDEX('(', english) - 1)
WHERE  (CHARINDEX('(', english) > 0)
```

But i get error:

> Token in error LEFT

How can i handle that?

Comment: have u considered cleaning your string using Regex and then simply update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LEFT` function is [apparently not supported in SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), but you can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275646%28SQL.80%29.aspx) instead.

I did a test and this worked fine:

```sql
UPDATE    dic
SET  english = SUBSTRING(english, 1, CHARINDEX('(', english) - 1)
WHERE  (CHARINDEX('(', english) > 0)
```

Comment: what happen if "(" is not present in my data??will it work fine ??

Comment: yes, the above statement only updates the three records that have a `(`

Comment: Can you help me how to delete duplicate row from a table in SqlCe @w0lf

Comment: @user2029069 it's better that you ask a different question for this. And make sure to mention the entire table structure (columns, primary key etc.)